# How to get list of all start up/login applications on mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to get a list/array of all the application that are launch at the startup Mac using objective c.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code to get all the applicaiton list from startup

```
     // Get the LoginItems list.
    LSSharedFileListRef loginItemsRef = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);
    if (loginItemsRef == nil) return nil;
    // Iterate over the LoginItems.
    NSArray *loginItems = (__bridge NSArray *)LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(loginItemsRef, nil);

   for (id item in loginItems) {
   // do what you want
   }
```